# django how to redirect url after remove item from cart redirect url

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views

this is my url where I want to redirect after post :

```
path('edit/<int:blerje_id>/produkti/add/', views.add_choice, name="add_choice"),
```

url remove:

```
path('clear/<int:prod_id>/', views.clear, name='clear'),
```

this is my view:

```
def clear(request,prod_id):
prod= get_object_or_404(Prod, id=prod_id)
prod.delete() 
return redirect('polls:add_choice', blerje_id=blerje.pk)
```

name 'blerje' is not defined

Comment: How’s does your Prod model relate to your Blerje model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return redirect('polls:add_choice', blerje_id=prod.blerje.pk)